# Two collection views for different data or one?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am currently using a single collectionview to present user data on a news feed. At the moment I am using a single collectionview to present the data and have two data sources for two different views. I am using class variables to switch between the two data sources using a segmented control such as...

```
@IBAction func segmentSelected(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        userSchool = false
        following = true
        collectionView.reloadData()
        break

    case 1:
        userSchool = true
        following = false
        collectionView.reloadData()
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

I have a "if" statement in my collection view stubs that correctly change the data. My question is, would it be better for performance if I used two different collection views and adjusted the code accordingly, or continued to use one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From an architectural point of view I must say one view, as long as the data source are two different objects representing the two different sets of data. Performance wise, UITableView is optimised to reuse cells and keep in memory just the ones that are currently visible on screen (plus some buffer) and in normal conditions it never query to the datasource for elements that are not in the visible rect.

I would say one view is performance wise and architecturally the best choice in my opinion.

**Note**: When I say 2 different datasource I literally mean 2 instances of two different objects representing the first set of data and the second. So I would expect somewhere in your switch statement `collectionView.dataSource = ...` in both cases.